# Asp.Net Core Web APi and Azure AD auth

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have to create a web app with these kinds of requirements:

- SPA (Angular 9)
- SPA call to Web API (Asp.net core 3.1)
- I have to use the Azure AD for
  the authentication (I created the tenant)
- I have to use Microsoft Graph API

I read different guides and studied the examples at the link
[azure ad auth samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/enable-webapp-signin/)
but they do not cover my requirements.
I read this guide [a web api that calls a web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore) that use a desktop application but after changing the code i receive the 401 unouthorized error.

Can anyone help me?

P.S. : Due unsuitable examples, i currently no have exutable code

Thanks a lot

Comment: According to my understanding, your web API is protected by Azure AD and your web API will call Microsoft graph. Right?

Comment: yes it is correct, now I can get the access token with MSAL from the angular application and the i call the my web api and receive error 500.
this is the error

Comment: An error occurred sending the request.\r\n\r\n ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'accountIdentifier')\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserFromCacheAsync(IConfidentialClientApplication application, String accountIdentifier, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String loginHint, String tenant)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserFromCacheAsync(IConfidentialClientApplication application, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String tenant)\r\n   at

Comment: Hi @Salvo12, I have the same requirement. Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @shyambabu I have a sample project where the Angular SPA and ASP.Net Web API work together after authentication with Azure AD (and Angular calls Graph API separately).  If you want to call Graph API from Web API you can do so with a "On-Behalf-Of" flow as mentioned by Nan Yu. https://github.com/superman-lopez/AzureAd_AspNet_Angular

Comment: @Superman.Lopez, Let me get back after looking into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [MSAL For Angular document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) for how to authenticate user and acquire access token  . And [this code sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/angular9-sample-app) is for Angular 9 .

If you want to directly call Microsfot Graph in Angular application , you can directly acquire Microsoft Graph's scopes as the document show , MSAL will help acquiring access token for Microsoft Graph . If you want to call Microsoft Graph from web api application , propagate the delegated user identity and permissions , you can use [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) and follow the code sample as your shown , and use fiddler or developer tools to trace the requests and troubleshoot the 401 problem .